# Trying to convert object mapper model to array

Tags: arrays, swift, object, objectmapper

I'm new to Swift and have asked a few questions that I was somewhat confused about how to get the correct type for my object, but I believe I've figured it out.

I have a User object that is an Object Mapper model.

I am trying to convert this Object Mapper model to an Array.

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

However I am getting the error `Cannot specialize a non-generic definition`

Here is the variable I am trying to cast:

```
fileprivate var userDataSource = Mapper<User>().Array<Any>(User)
```

And an extension for its definition:

```
extension AccountViewController: GetUserDelegate {
    func getUserSuccess(user: User) {
        self.userDataSource = User
    }
}
```

The original mapping to a model is done here:

```
guard let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSONObject: value)
```

The user class looks like this:

```
class User: Mappable {
    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    init() {}

    var id: Int?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var displayName: String?
    var image: URL?
    var about: String?
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
    var authToken: String?
```

I can include more if desired.

What am I misunderstanding here? None of the examples I'm seeing for this error really seem to apply to my situation.

Desired ultimate output:

```
["Name", "Bob Jim"],
["MC #", "1234567"],
["Company Name", "Bob's Truckin"],
["Truck Type", "Flat Bed"],
["Cell", "(555) 555-5555"],
["Dispatch", "(999) 999-9999"],
["Favorite Destinations", "Los Angeles"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather you want an array of Users as the datasource, 
I'd declare it like any other array:

```
var userDataSource = [User]()
```

or

```
var userDataSource = Array<User>()
```

And to update the datasource,

```
extension AccountViewController: GetUserDelegate {
    func getUserSuccess(user: User) {
        self.userDataSource.append(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I want an array of user properties, with the property name as value[0] and the value as [1]. The endpoint, as far as I'm reading above, should only give one user.

Comment: I'll include the desired output.

Comment: Your desired output is really odd, I'd recommend a dictionary. You can use `Mapper().toJSON(userObject)`

Comment: Wouldn't that give me JSON, not an array?

Comment: Arrays are usually a list of same kind of objects, while dictionary is key-value pairs like: ["Name": "Bob Jim","MC #": "1234567"], So it's more suited.

Comment: I'm not sure how an array would help your use case.

Comment: I agree. But that's not how the code was written by another person so far. I can work on refactoring that later. Right now I need to have this work as written unfortunately.

Comment: When trying to use this line of code: fileprivate var userDataSource = Mapper().Array<Any>(User) I am still getting the non-generic definition error. What is causing that?